# Include a module with or without send, is there any difference?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
SomeClass.include(SomeModule)
```

vs.

```
SomeClass.send :include, SomeModule
```

Is there any differences between them? Why is the second way preferred? (At least I've found it more frequently in other people's code).

Comment: #include is a private method (unless you've changed its visibility), so the difference is that one raises an error and the other works.

Comment: @andrew First of all: curiosity. Secondly, I'm writing some helper methods that will interact with `ActiveRecord::Base` objects, so I thought it'd be a good idea if I added those methods to `ActiveRecord::Base` itself. I find `object.method` communicates better than `method(object)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are **almost** identical.

The difference is that if `SomeClass#include` is private, the latter will still be able to call it due to the nature of `Object#send`

If `SomeClass#include` was private and you went with the former, it would raise an error.

So the advantage of using the latter is that you can include a module no matter what the visibility is. (Whether or not you actually believe accessing private methods is the "right" thing to do is another story. It certainly gives you tremendous power).

Comment: +1 good point about visibility of include method, which is private by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-open an existing class:

```
class SomeClass
  include SomeModule
end
```

Comment: the difference is that this one makes things harder to debug: if you call SomeClass.send(xxx) but the class isn't there, you'll get an error, while if you reopen a class you may be creating it for real.

Comment: I didn't dive into that option - can't tell!